# How to change WindowStyle with UseShellExecute on false?

Tags: c#, process, redirectstandardoutput

I'm starting some executables with the System.Diagnostics.Process Class like following:

C# Code:

```
Process newProcess = new Process();
newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = path;
newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = parameter;
newProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
newProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = windowStyle;
newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
newProcess.Start();
```

Everything works except that the `WindowStyle` is not set as I want it. It keeps on the default value. If the `UseShellExecute` is set on true, the `WindowStyle` changes like I want it but I can't use the `RedirectStandardError` and `RedirectStandardOutput` anymore since it requires `UseShellExecute` on false. I was looking for an answer but didn't find anything to expect that you can't set `UseShellExecute` to false and edit the `WindowStyle`. Is this true?

What approach could I use to get the Standard and Error Output and still be able to change the `WindowStyle`?

Comment: So wait, is this a command line tool you're executing? I'm not sure WindowStyle can affect the look of the command prompt window.

Comment: @Nyerguds it can be any executable, I tried it with notepad.exe

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue : RedirectStandardOutput requires UseShellExecute to be false, and WindowStyle only works when UseShellExecute is true.

The following works for me **after** starting the process :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
static int SW_HIDE = 0;

// Wait a little for the process to start otherwise handle is 0
IntPtr mainHandle = newProcess.MainWindowHandle;
bool result = ShowWindow(mainHandle, SW_HIDE);
```

Two inconveniencies compared to StartInfo.WindowStyle :

1. The window appears briefly before disappearing
2. It only works **after** starting the process, unlike WindowStyle. To make sure the process has started I read its first line of output.